# How to manipulate list of item from an Observable with value of another Observable

Tags: rxjs

Here my problem.

Suppose i have an observable with a list of countries and another observable returns a traduction according to a key.

```
interface CountryCode {
 id: number;
 code: string;
}

interface Country implements CountryCode {
 name: string;
}

public getCountries():Observable<CountryCode[]>{
    return Observable.of([{id:1,code:'fr'},{id:2,code:'en'}];
}

public getTrad(key: string):Observable<string> {
    const trad = {fr: 'France',en: 'Angleterre'};
    return Observable.of(trad[key]);
}
```

How can i do to have at the end :

```
[{id:1, name:'France', code:'fr'},{id:2, name:'Angleterre', code:'en'}]
```

My trouble its to work with the second observable.

```
    const countries$: Observable<Country[]> = this.getCountries()
        .map(items => items.map(
             item => assign(item, {name: this.getTrad(item.code)}))); //wont work
```

This doesn't work because i have ScalarObservable

Comment: So basically you want to _extend_ the objects in the first collection with the `name` property, by combining an object on the second collection matched through the `code` property, right?

Comment: That's right, by the way i made mistake in my answer.
it is : [{id:1,code:'fr'},{id:2,code:'en'}]
and [{id:1, name:'France', code:'fr'},{id:2, name:'Angleterre', code:'en'}]

I need to access of each item from the first observable and to get the name from the other observable.

Comment: Please update with the correct expected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```
import { flatMap, mergeMap, toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';

const countries$: Observable<Country[]> = this.getCountries()
        .pipe(
          // flatten the array in order to operate with the singular elements
          // note that `flatMap` is just an alias for `mergeMap`
          flatMap(countryCodes => countryCodes),
          // combine the source observable, a country code, with 
          // another observable
          mergeMap(countryCode => this.getTrad(countryCode.code)
             .pipe(map(name => ({name, ...countryCode})))),
          // collect the single elements into a new array
          toArray()
        );
```

Comment: `flatMap` and `mergeMap` are the same thing.

Comment: Yup, but the `flatMap` alias is easier to understand than `mergeMap`, specially for the use case of simple array flattening.

Comment: what is the purpose of pipe ?

Comment: See https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.3.3/doc/pipeable-operators.md